# Slow performance of C++ std::filesystem::directory_iterator for symlinks

Tags: c++, c++17

I understand std::filesystem is not a speed demon. But compared to `opendir/readdir` I see execution times for `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` being a factor 8-10 larger (Ubuntu 18.04, clang 9.0.0). Now I wonder if I do something wrong or at least hope for some insight why it is (so much) slower.

In more detail: I'm comparing these two, almost identical functions:

```
    int32_t GetNumberOfFilesStdFilesys(const std::filesystem::path& testDir) {
    // Find all files in that testDir
    int32_t numFiles = 0;
    for (auto& dirent : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(testDir)) {
        if (dirent.is_regular_file() || dirent.is_symlink()) {
            // const std::string filename(dirent.path().filename());
            numFiles++;
        }
    }
    return numFiles;
}

int32_t GetNumberOfFilesStdC(const std::filesystem::path& testDir) {
    // Find all files in that testDir
    int32_t numFiles = 0;
    DIR* dir = opendir(testDir.string().c_str());
    for (struct dirent* entry = readdir(dir); entry != NULL; entry = readdir(dir
)) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG || entry->d_type == DT_LNK) {
            // const std::string filename(entry->d_name);
            numFiles++;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return numFiles;
}
```

They walk over a directory and count the regular and symbolic-link entries. I then run this in a loop 30000 times for a directory with 100 symlinks and 300 times for a directory with 10000 symlinks. Here the result:

```
Symlink (Number Files: 100, Iterations: 30000)
    Std C lib       CPU time: 443.91 msec       Wall clock: 446.97 msec
    std::filesystem     CPU time: 3908.20 msec      Wall clock: 3910.18 msec
Symlink (Number Files: 10000, Iterations: 300)
    Std C lib       CPU time: 455.26 msec       Wall clock: 455.92 msec
    std::filesystem     CPU time: 5090.57 msec      Wall clock: 5090.61 msec
```

the CPU time is measured with `std::clock` and the Walltime with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.
I assume that `directory_iterator` is processing more data, maybe following the symlink (?) - are there any flags to prevent this?
Or is this simply the price of platform abstraction?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Looks like at least libstdc++'s implementation calls `stat` on each file instead of using the info from the `dirent`.

Comment: My apology, it's actually clang 9.0.0, not gcc. The list from "bazel build -s " is really long but I could identify "-O3" as the generic optimization flag.

Comment: @mbind Clang may be using either libc++ or libstdc++. It would probably be helpful to know which one you are using since their implementations may differ.

Comment: Indeed, at least from my reading it looks like libc++ _does_ pass the info from the `dirent` down into the `std::directory_entry` when iterating a directory and check that for the `is_*` functions, while libstdc++ does not.

Comment: libstdc++'s `path` representation is also quite expensive (and a `directory_entry` is basically required to contain a `path` even though your example never uses it), which likely contributes to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! The numbers above are with libc++ 9.0.0 as standard lib.
I'm installing a clean VM (ongoing as we speak) with clang9.0.0 to reproduce this "off" our production build system to confirm the numbers

Comment: `is_regular_file` does resolve symlinks. `is_symlink` doesn't. What happens if you reverse the order in the `||`?

Comment: @T.C.: marvelous! This change of sequence gets above numbers down to below 800msec for the std::filesystem, comparable with regular file access.
Confusing that is_regular_file() is resolving symlinks - I expected simply a check of the file the path is pointing too. Just learned the value of looking into the stdlib code - thank you!